# Using the C preprocessor of Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor

I would like to invoke a C preprocessor on some arbitrary text (no C code).  Can I use the preprocessing facilities of the compiler that comes with Visual Studio 2015?  It doesn't come with the `cl` compiler anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot use Visual Studio 2015 Instead of this try using any flavor of Linux. It provides gcc compiler that will be helpful in your work. And please elaborate your question for more perfect answer.

Comment: Your answer is already perfect: I cannot use Visual Studio and I must use an another tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this via the command line tools that come with Visual Studio (including free versions) if you have C/C++ features installed.  Specifically, look for [CL.exe which supports preprocessing (/P)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx).

If you're running Windows 10, you also have the option to install the [Linux subsystem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/) and run the usual GCC toolset natively as well.